# Converting array of xml elements to an array of floats?

Tags: objective-c, xml, xcode, arrays, parsing

I have the following problem:
I am parsing a XML file, that contains a few **"chas"** elements. I save them in an array - arrayBegin. How to convert every object of the array to float ? I am a newbie, so I am really sorry for the dumb question. Thanks in advance! Here is my code:

```
    NSString *dayToString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://pik.bg/TV/bnt1/02.04.2013.xml"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:dayToString];
    NSData *webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    // every <chas> element from the xml file
    NSString *xPathQueryBegin = @"//elem/chas";
    TFHpple *parserBegin = [TFHpple hppleWithXMLData:webData];
    NSArray *arrayBegin = [parserBegin searchWithXPathQuery:xPathQueryBegin];
    NSLog (@"%d", [arrayBegin count]);
```

Comment: NSString has a `floatValue` method, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Can you give me an example, please? You can use my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By this:

```
NSMutableArray *floatArray=[NSMutableArray new];
for(NSString *string in arrayBegin){
    floatArray[floatArray.count]=@([string floatValue]);
}
```

Comment: @scourGINHO "doesn't work" is uninformative. **In what way** doesn't it work? The code Anoop provided seems fine.

Comment: "{\n    nodeChildArray =     (\n                {\n            nodeContent = \"09.00\";\n            nodeName = text;\n        }\n    );\n    nodeName = chas;\n}",
    "{\n    nodeChildArray =     (\n                {\n            nodeContent = \"09.10\";\n            nodeName = text;\n        }\n    );\n    nodeName = chas;\n}", ETC...

Comment: What do you mean? What else do I need to do to complete the parse?

Comment: You are still having `"{\n nodeChildArray = (\n {\n nodeContent = \"09.00\";\n nodeName = text;\n }\n );\n nodeName = chas;\n}",` parse it to find only **nodeContent**

Comment: Thanks, I did what u tell me. I tried adding your code after that, but  there's an erorr: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Listing floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7187760'

Comment: This is my array when I use NSLog to display it:     "<Listing: 0x7191df0>", "<Listing: 0x7196be0>", "<Listing: 0x7196cb0>", ETC...

Comment: Listing looks to be an object, you need to retrieve float value or string value from there.